# C# - Value of '10000' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I have a web browser progressbar. And the code is:

```
   private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = unchecked((int)e.CurrentProgress);
    }
```

And when I play the app. Its gives an error:

`Value of '10000' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'.`

so is there any way to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either provide a value for the current progress that is between the min and max you specified when you created the progress bar (it will be 0 - 100 by default if you didn't specify them) or change the min/max to be what is actually expected of the values you are currently passing.

Comment: ok i set the minimum and maximum values but now another error occurs `Value of '-1' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'.` and we can not set the minimum value to less than 0.

Comment: @HaseebAhmadBasil Then you'll need to ensure you don't ever pass a value that's less than 0.  You may need to normalize your values to be within the given range if what you really want to represent includes negative values.

Comment: how can I include negative values and other thing is that I'm not giving the negative values my self the values are given by the browser.

Comment: @HaseebAhmadBasil If the minvalue cannot be negative, then you cannot give a negative value.  You'll need to adjust the value to be on a positive scale first.  If you know the lowest possible negative value, just add the absolute value of that to both the max and current value; now all of your values are positive.

Comment: _If the minvalue cannot be negative_ - as I remember it can, isn't it?

Comment: @Qwertiy I know it's old, but [`ArgumentException`: The value specified for the property is less than 0.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbar.minimum?view=net-5.0) - so apparently `Minimum` can't be negative

Comment: @Rafalon, strange, but ok.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that `Value` is between `Minimum` and `Maximum`. Therefore when you set up your progress bar ensure that you give it an adequate range.

Answer (score 0):

ProgressBars normally have a Minimum and Maximum that needs to be set first.

These properties are what tells the control how far the draw progress should be drawn. Value 50 in 1-100 range would tell it that it wanted to draw the progress 50%.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.maximum.aspx